# Android Video Camera Resolution via Intent

Tags: android

For my App, I want to be able to capture video in various resolutions/qualities.
As per API there are only two options: 0 or 1:

```
    Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
```

How do I set video resolution: 1 gives best possible 1080p, and 0 gives MMS quality (horrible).

ICS Android native camera gives 3 options: SD, 720p, 1080p, How do I get those.

Answer (score 2):

Using the intent for recording video, as you noted, you have two choices....  If you
want more choices, you will need to write your own video recorder.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video for more
information.  VERY IMPORTANT:  Note the section on MediaRecorder that gives you the
options and the sequence that they MUST be entered in.  Among those you will find options for video size, frame rate, audio and video encoding bit rates, etc.

Later,
   --jim

Comment: Well, thats what I was using initially. But shooting at resolutions other than max delivers sub 15fps in video. I want pure 30fps at 740p or 480p.

Comment: Did you set the frame rate when you did this?  Did it default to    < 15 fps?  Or did it just not have the performance to go above      15 fps?  If performance was not the issue, make sure you set the frame rate to 30 fps (actually, that's 29.97 fps, but it's common to list it as 30 fps).

Comment: setVideoFrameRate(30); but camera happily ignores it.

Comment: Did you set EVERYTHING in the right order, as I referred to above?  If you did, and you set it to a valid (i.e., supported) frame rate, I don't know what to tell you.  If not, re-read the dev guide link I posted above.  You can't just set one thing...you MUST set them in the right order.

Comment: I'm sure its in the right order, I took official API samples. From my observations, different devices behave differently. Some devices allow 30fps only at specific resolutions. e.g. Transformer prime allows 30fps at 1080p only anything below that ( 720p, 480p or VGA) is 15FPS. Which is weird.